# Can this idea give rise to a proof of the 2-dimensional Borsuk-Ulam theorem?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This post is not meant to be very rigorous; rather, I'd like to know if all the suggested steps *can* be made rigorous. (If this has already been done, feel free to just cite a relevant source.) It would be great if someone could highlight the key/tricky points in this approach and the tools needed to take care of all problems. So here's a sketch of [Borsuk-Ulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) in 2 dimensions, which states that any continuous map $f:S^2 \to R^2$ attains the same value on a pair of antipodal points. First, note that such a map is equivalent to two coordinate scalar fields $f_i:S^2 \to R$, $i=1,2$.

1. Assume Borsuk-Ulam holds one dimension (it follows from the intermediate value theorem).
2. Cover the sphere in a continuous $S^1$-parameter family of great circles (e.g. the meridians).
3. For each of these great circles, apply the one-dimensional Borsuk-Ulam theorem to the restriction of the scalar field $f_i$ to the great circle to obtain a pair $(x_i,x_i')$ of antipodal points such that $f_i(x_i) = f_i(x_i')$.
4. Assuming that this procedure is continuous, and applying it on each great circle, yields two loops $l_i$ ($i=1,2$) on $S^2$, each consisting of the (many) points $x_i$ above along with their antipodes $x_i'$.
5. Argue that two such loops (consisting of points along with their antipodes) must intersect on $S^2$. By construction, a point in the intersection along with its antipode (also in the intersection) will satisfy the two-dimensional Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

What do you think? Thank you for reading!

Comment: I remember thinking about this same method, but never checking the details. The delicate part is point 4, the "continuity" of the procedure, also because you could have many $x_i$ which satisfy point 3, therefore obtaining many ramified loops. Of course this seems even better to reach the goal, but it introduces some choices to make in order to obtain a single continuous loop around the meridians.